# Swift How to make links open in Webview?

Tags: ios, swift, button, webview, hyperlink

I can't find solution for this. I hope You'll help me.
I want buttons with hyperlinks to open websites in webview on second screen. Hyperlink opens in safari and I want it to open on second screen in webview.
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a UIWebView to my iOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408746/how-do-i-add-a-uiwebview-to-my-ios-app)

Answer (score 19):

You can use SFSafariViewController to open link in your application, here is the code for that

First you need to import SafariServices

```
import SafariServices
```

then on the button action, you can open `SFSafariViewController`

**For swift 3.0**

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string:"http://stackoverflow.com")!)
self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")! as URL)` why not just `URL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!`?

Comment: @JAL I am quite new to swift, thank for correcting me :)

Comment: @JAL if you do the code in swift3 then you can write like that

Comment: oh my god, this must be the 3rd time a solution was extremely simple but so hard to find on the internet because the practices and available tools keep changing and 90% of answers are outdated! Eveone else is saying we have to implement our own UIWebView

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.1 and Swift 5**. If there are some links inside the app then it will open in safari, So to opens the links within same webview implement following **navigationDelegate** fo **WKWebView**.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
     if navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationType.linkActivated {
        webView.load(navigationAction.request)
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
     }
     decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void){

```
        if let url = navigationAction.request.url, let scheme = url.scheme?.lowercased() {

            if scheme == "https" || scheme == "http"{
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url){
                    // use the available apps in user's phone
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                }
            }
        }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
```

}